# How to create a header for perl?

Tags: perl

I am new to perl. I wish to create a perl program which sends request to a website and downloads the data. I read `HTTP::Headers` and `HTTP::Request`.

I wish to use `HTTP::Request->new( 'POST', $URL, $Header, $PostData )`.

My question is how can I determine header values and post data.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was creating a similar script sometime back. I think first you should capture the http request using the browser.

1) Add "HTTPFox" to firefox. It is very helpful.

2) Open HttpFox in a new window. Press start button. This will start capturing packets.

3) Open the website and follow the procedures to download the data.

Please ask if anything is not clear.